# How can we cache a json file in server in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I need to cache a json file in the server so that each time we don't need to load it from the server. 
How can I do that in Express js ?
Also how can I get those data from the file in the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For writing

```
fs.writeFile('file-name.json', jsonData, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

For reading you can simply require it

```
var jsonData = require('file-name.json')
```

When you `required` file, its cached and doesn`t loads on every request.

Comment: That's really cool. I didn't realize you could one time open and cache files like that just by requiring them.

Comment: Thankyou.. :)
I didn't knew about cache in 'require'